# Python Subpackages - Absolute Import Failure

Tags: python, module, package

This question has been asked in different contexts, but I still am unable to get a successful absolute import.

I have this directory structure

```
21:48:07$ tree
start_dir
└── top_package
    ├── README.md
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   └── secrets.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── subpackage1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── secrets.py
    └── subpackage2
        └── __init__.py
```

All I want to be able to do is from **test.py** be able to import from secrets. Here is the contents of test.py:

```
# import top_package # ImportError: No module named top_package
# from top_package import secrets # ImportError: No module named top_package

import top_package.secrets # ImportError: No module named top_package
```

None of these have worked. I've read through multiple pages on having multiple subpackages in a top level package but still no dice.

Is this simply because I'm trying to execute the file directly by running `python test.py` instead of calling this from start_dir? If so, what's the best way to develop and work around this?

**Goal: I want to be able to absolute `import secrets` from `test.py`. If possible, I do not want to do anything with the site-packages or with the `setup.py`. I want to be able to run `python test.py` and have the line: `import top_package` not give a ImportError no module found**. Please advise the best course of action.

Comment: I deleted the redundant answer and you might want to edit your question and clearly mention what you wished to do so that others can find it useful:)

Comment: Sure thanks. I edited it but let me know if it's not clear and I can continue to tweak it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Python doesn't look for packages throughout the system, there are specific paths where it looks and if found, executes the import. I don't think there would be a way you can have a package anywhere in your system and be able to absolute import it. This way it would take ages just to run imports. But I'll surely let you know if I find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

So you created `top_package` and want to `import` it anywhere within your system. You can do so by copying the package folder to the `site-packages` folder of your environment. This is a path where python would look while importing packages.